# Trying to delete the selected item in the XPages repeat control, but does not work

Tags: xpages, controls, repeat, delete-row

I am trying to delete the selected item in the Xpages repeat control, but it does not work. Please help?
Here is my code in the repeat control section

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="eachQuestion" value="#{questions}"
                indexVar="rowIndex">
<tr>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>  <xp:link     styleClass="btn btn-danger" id="deleteLink">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClick"
        action="#{javascript:eachQuestion.getDocument().remove(true);}"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="listContainer" />
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash-o" />
    </xp:link> </td>
</tr>
</xp:repeat>
```

Here is what I can see in the client page, generated html and JS code:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:repeat1:0:_id44","view:_id1:repeat1:0:deleteLink", null, "onClick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:listContainer");
```

When I click the delete link icon, nothing happened.
I realized function(){}  nothing in there. 
Is there anything wrong or I have to implement the method in the Java code to handle this deletion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change "on**C**lick" to "on**c**lick" in your code and it will work.

Case sensitivity does matter in Xpages. So, your code to delete a document is right but the event "onClick" doesn't gets executed at all.

Comment: You've got sharp eyes, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what "questions" is.  I assume it's a view.  The code looks right to me.  You certainly do NOT need Java to delete a document from a rpw in a repeat control.

I would ignore the client side stuff. That's server generated.  It's supposed to be empty I think.  The server knows what to do.

First check the database ACL.  Make sure the user has delete access.  I'd also add a Display Errors control on the page.  If it's not deleting due to a validation issue it should show there.  Then I'd go to OpenNTF and get the XPages Log Reader control.  It's a small xpages database that let's you see errors more easily.

I'd start with those ideas.

By the way that's not a good way to do a table in a repeat control.  It should be producing invalid HTML.  You should use Facets.  That is NOT your problem though.

Comment: Yes you are right, "questions" is the view declared before these code. I checked the ACL, looks fine for me. I add the Display Errors control on the page, but nothing in  the box after I clicked the link.
    <xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
Do i need do something in the code to fire this message?